# View behind ScrollView or not? And how to do so with storyboard

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, uiscrollview, storyboard

I use a UIScrollView for some of my views to display some long textviews. I'm using XCode 4 and in the Storyboard I have placed the UIScrollView directly onto the ViewController scene.

Now I see in tutorials and stuff that people have a regular View between the view controller and scrollview. Is there a reason for doing that?

I've tried doing the same in my app following [this](http://www.geekylemon.com/WEBPROTECT-xcodescroll.htm) tutorial, but I can't make it work with the storyboard, can't find the connection etc..

It looks like it works fine doing it my way in the simulator, but should I find a way to put a view behind it for some reason? If so, how can I do that properly with the storyboard?

Here's code for how I've done it, + made the connection from the Outlet to the ScrollView in the Storyboard.

InfoViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface InfoViewController : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *theScroller;
}

@end
```

InfoViewController.m

```
#import "InfoViewController.h"

@interface InfoViewController ()

@end

@implementation InfoViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [theScroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [theScroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,750)];

    self.navigationItem.title = @"Title";
}
@end
```

PS. I can't find a way to scroll down through the scrollview in the storyboard, it doesn't work to just scroll on it with the mouse if thats the way, have my way to set this up maybe disabled this..?

And when thinking about it: If I want the scrollview to be smaller than the View itself, I should put it inside a view in the storyboard, right? So if you know a tutorial on how to do that or if you can describe the procedure, feel free to.

Comment: Your tutorial link is asking for account registration ?

Comment: @SALMAN It was someone else upvoting it the first time, then I upvoted+accepted. ;-)